# How can to_tsquery() return a value that does not match the searched value?

Tags: sql, postgresql, search, full-text-search, tsvector

Can someone explain to me how this:

```
SELECT description, description_search
FROM my_table 
WHERE description_search @@ to_tsquery('ins:*')
```

can return this:

```
description: 
'The leap second configuration has been updated.
Reason: Leap second data initialized from registry during boot
Leap seconds enabled: true
New leap second count: 0
Old leap second count: 0'

description_search:
'0':25,30 'boot':16 'configur':4 'count':24,29 'data':11 'enabl':19 'initi':12 
'leap':2,9,17,22,27 'new':21 'old':26 'reason':8 'registri':14 'second':3,10,18,23,28 
'true':20 'updat':7
```

when no words in the returned string matches 'ins:*'?

Comment: It's working OK on my endpoint. SELECT   '0:25,30 boot:16 configur:4 count:24,29 data:11 enabl:19 initi:12 
leap:2,9,17,22,27 new:21 old:26 reason:8 registri:14 second:3,10,18,23,28 
true:20 updat:7'::tsvector 
@@ to_tsquery('ins:*')

Comment: @MitkoKeckaroski What does it return?

Comment: to_tsquery('ins:*') returning "false"

Comment: to_tsquery('boot:*') returning "true"

Comment: @MitkoKeckaroski I literally copy pasted your code with  to_tsquery('ins:*') and it returns true for me...

Comment: @MitkoKeckaroski to_tsquery('boot:*') also returning "true", to_tsquery('inst:*') returning "false".. I'm very confused how "ins:*" can return true...

Comment: Try to specify "english" as language. Here is a list of available languages. SELECT cfgname FROM pg_ts_config;  [doc](https://www.compose.com/articles/mastering-postgresql-tools-full-text-search-and-phrase-search/)

Comment: @MitkoKeckaroski I don't think it will do anything since the default is already english. Anyways I've tried it and it's exactly same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at what to_tsquery returns.

```
select to_tsquery('ins:*');
 to_tsquery 
------------
 'in':*
(1 row)
```

So 'ins:*' gets stemmed to 'in:*' (for English anyway), and 'in:*' obviously matches 'initi'

Don't use to_tsquery() if you have already written the query yourself.  Just use the query your wrote, `'ins:*'::tsquery`

Comment: Aah, that makes sense.. Thank you very much!!